# как получить доменное имя бекенда внутри react-app по имени контейнера в котором хостуется бэкенд в рамках 1 docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

> (эта конфигурация уже работает ,но я хочу автоматически определять REACT_APP_API_DOMAIN по имени контейнера в docker-compose)

файл внутри react-app в котором я хочу воспользоваться прокинутым путём к бекенду

```
 const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_DOMAIN + '/',
})
```

Dockerfile.dev запускает react-app

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-compose.dev.yml запускает весь проект в режиме разработки

```
version: '3.0'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11.2
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    networks:
      - nesjs-network
    volumes:
      - ./src/server/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./src/server/postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
    logging:
      driver: none
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

  react-client:
    depends_on:
      - backend
    build:
      context: ./src/react-client/
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    restart: always
#    image: romangodmode/react_client_dev:1.0.0

    env_file:
      - ./src/react-client/.env.development

    container_name: react_client_dev
    ports:
    - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./src/react-client:/usr/src/app/

  backend:
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: nestjs_api_dev
    build:
      context: ./src/server/
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    env_file:
      - .env.development
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - nesjs-network

    volumes:
      - ./src/server:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    restart: always

networks:
  nesjs-network:
```

.env.development файл с переменными где я вручную присвоил REACT_APP_API_DOMAIN значение

```
REACT_APP_API_DOMAIN=http://localhost:8080
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Comment: а зачем? react это фрейморк для клиентских приложений, которые работают в браузере, т.е. запросу к бекенду отправляются не из контейнера, а от клиентского браузера, который может находиться где угодно, и не иметь доступ к внутренней сети докера, и у вас это работает, т.к. вы хостите и проверяете в браузере одной машины, а идея пробрасывать url через env мне кажется вполне нормальной

Comment: предполагается что моя система - монолит(бд+бекенд+реакт), и я хочу по одной команде docker-compose up хостить без дополнительной настройки и переписывания переменных
(я знаю что многие не в восторге от докера на проде, но мне очень хочется сделать именно это)